# How to fix kitchen sink leak

Tags: kitchens, leak, sink

Can anyone help with this leak under my kitchen sink? It randomly started a day ago for no reason. Do we just need to try to tighten the nut? The photo shows where it’s actively leaking without the faucet being turned on. Thank you! Not handy people but would love to not call out a plumber. [image]

Comment: Those appear to be compression fittings (and commonly are) which means tape won't help a bit. Indeed, it would appear it's already been misapplied to them, and that may be part of the problem.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Good catch on the possibility of being compression fittings. You see my glasses anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The messing part is a compression fitting and the chrome part a seal fitting. Tape does not solve your problem. If the compression fitting is leaking you need to replace the ring. If the seal fitting is leaking, turn off the water and disassemble the two parts. Thereafter you would be able to see where it is leaking. Anyway I propose to replace both the compression ring and the seal.

Answer (score 0):

OK, shut the water off and try to tighten both nuts. Then turn the water back on and observe. If it's still leaking, turn off the water again and remove both those nuts since we're not exactly sure where the leak is. Get some plumber's thread seal tape (the white stuff) and wrap a couple turns clockwise around the male threads and reinstall the nuts and tighten. If they are compression fitting, you won't need the tape. You should be good to go. OH, turn the water back on.

Comment: The messing part is a compression fitting and the chrome part a seal fitting. Tape does not solve the problem

Comment: @Decapod  I did mention tape wouldn't be needed if compression. Disassembling and reassembling  solves a lot of problems, so does tightening. I still up voted you.